# Can firebase.js be used to implement multi player games?

Tags: javascript, websocket, firebase

I am using Firebase.js for realtime chat synch and I wonder if it's possible to make a game like typeracer.com with Firebase, that detects moves and displays in real time. If Firebase can not do it, please tell me how I can build it with other technologies. thank you.

Comment: One of the older demos I remember for Firebase was this multiplayer Asteroids: http://www.mmoasteroids.com/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for help, I really want to build multiplayer games, but it's so difficult, can you help me  :(

Comment: if you are stuck on a specific problem, just reproduce that problem in a small program and post it here at Stack Overflow. I created a multi-player typing game with Firebase, so can say from experience that it is possible. And using Firebase sure beats the common alternative: brewing the whole browser-to-browser communication protocol yourself.

Comment: why is this voted as too broad?

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible. Check out the [Tetris example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/examples.html) if you haven't already!